# How do I configure a phone number format?

Tags: contacts, localisation

Where do I set a phone number format (like date or address options at Administer/Localization)? Thank you.  I'm on rev 4.6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - you can't.  Phone numbers are entered as free entry text.  That's different from addresses, where the format is about which order different fields fall in; phone numbers are only one field.  Dates aren't stored as freeform text; they're stored in a specialized "date" field to handle this.

That said, there's an extension called [CiviDesk Normalize](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.normalize), and one of its functions is to store the phone numbers in a uniform format.  However, you don't get to choose the format (except "National" or "International" style).

From the code:

> INTERNATIONAL and NATIONAL formats are consistent with
>   the definition in ITU-T Recommendation E123.

If you have access to a developer who knows PHP, they can probably edit the format with a line or two of code - but I suspect it's more important that the phone numbers be uniform than the actual formatting!

Answer (score 3):

Another normalization tool specifically for phone numbers. Per the readme, it is an administrator tool, not a real time validator.

https://github.com/JohnFF/Phone-Number-Validator